# Moving from one activity to another activity (Viewpager)

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm new here. Actually I'm working on a project but not expert in android development. I wanna know that which piece of code should i use to move from one activity (button click) to another (viewpager) activity?
I tried simple code but app stopped running. Please guide me what to do?

A simple app, where user clicks on "Enter" button to see some pictures etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Button and you want to go to new activity when this particular button is clicked, you set `OnClickListener` on the button and use `Intent` to start new activity.

**Example:**

```
 btnNextScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {

             //create new intent
             Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondScreen.class);
             startActivity(nextScreen);
         }
 });
```

SecondScreen is the name of `.java` file of second activity that will be shown when `btnNextScreen` is clicked.